# Build Blender as a Python module with Draco compression enabled

Tags: python, gltf

I've succeed in building Blender as a Python module, but I would like to be able to use the draco compression when exporting glTF (gltb) files.
When building Blender as a Python module, I set CMake flags as indicated on the official wiki https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule:

```
WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=OFF
WITH_AUDASPACE=OFF
WITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON
WITH_INSTALL_PORTABLE=OFF
```

But, in the CMakeLists.txt there is an incompatibility between WITH_DRACO=ON and WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=OFF :

```
if(WITH_DRACO AND NOT WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL)
  message(STATUS "WITH_DRACO requires WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL to be ON, disabling WITH_DRACO for now")
  set(WITH_DRACO OFF)
endif()
```

And WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=ON is incompatible with WITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON:

```
# python module, needs some different options
if(WITH_PYTHON_MODULE AND WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "WITH_PYTHON_MODULE requires WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL to be OFF")
endif()
```

Is there any way to have Draco enabled when building Blender as a Python module ?

Thanks

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this issue? Anyone know why `WITH_DRACO requires WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL to be ON`? It's still the same situation with the latest Blender 3.6 LTS release.

Comment: I guess one simple solution is to do a regular GLB export and then use another lib like this: https://github.com/seung-lab/DracoPy